# How to verify if a class definition changed in running time? (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, pickle

My goal is to allow a class definition be updated in running time.

Therefore, when a class is loaded from a module, I snapshot the class definition (through serialization with pickle), calculating its md5 and saving {classname:md5chksum} in a dict

When a new class definition is loaded, the process is redone and, if the definition digest is present, compared.

The problem is that pickle by default avoids to perform recalculation, tracking the objects it has already serialized ([source](https://docs.python.or/3/library/pickle.html)).

Is there a way to disable its cache, something similar to [clear_memo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html%20clear_memo())() from python2.x?

Comment: _"The problem is that pickle by default avoids to perform recalculation, tracking the objects it has already serialized"_ Yes, but not across multiple calls of `pickle.dump`. If you'd tried it, you'd have realized that you're asking for a solution to a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: you are right, I was trying with pickle.dumps.
Thank you for pointing out.